# How to use a windows font in Qt application

Tags: c++, fonts, qt5, windows-7-x64

I have noticed that the default font Qt uses on windows 7 is slightly different to the system font.

It's clearly visible on letter 'o' in this example:

[image]  [image]

And here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow mainWin;

  QWidget* central = new QWidget(&mainWin);
  central->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);

  QPushButton* ba = new QPushButton("Tool A", central);
  central->layout()->addWidget(ba);

  QPushButton* bb = new QPushButton("Tool B", central);
  central->layout()->addWidget(bb);

  mainWin.setCentralWidget(central);
  mainWin.setWindowTitle("Tools");
  mainWin.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

How could I set exactly the same font in my application as windows uses?

Qt version: 5.7.1

Thanks!

Comment: these are two different sizes, and glyph shapes at low point sizes definitely rasterize differently, so have you tried matching size first, to see if they really are different or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution only works if you're on Windows. If that's not intended just use preprocessors!

The simple solution should be to use OS functions. This code should give you the name of the font.

```
//please note that this requires minimum Windows 7, for older versions a small change is needed over preprocessors
#include<Windows.h>
std::wstring getSystemDefaultFontName() {
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, ncm.cbSize, &ncm, 0);
    if (hr == 0)
        return std::wstring();
    return  std::wstring(ncm.lfMenuFont.lfFaceName); //There are different fonts for each section. I choose menu font but something else may be better?
}
```

For Qt simply say:

```
QFont systemFont(QString::fromWCharArray(getSystemDefaultFontName().c_str()), 8, QFont::Bold, true);
QApplication::setFont(systemFont);
```

***However please keep in mind, that the fonts can still look slightly different because Qt may render fonts different in comparison to Windows.***